# Shell Script code yields same output on update input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, backup, gnome

I have written script to add pattern of directories in exclude-list of Deja-Dup (backup softaware). Even I have updated values for `gsettings get org.gnome.DejaDup  include-list` and tested on terminal that it gives desired output, my code is producing same output which was to old input.

I have tried running `clear` and `reset` on terminal but it did not helped.

```
y=$(gsettings get org.gnome.DejaDup  include-list)

# Code to show included directory
ILS="" read -ra "x" <<<y
declare p INCLUDE_LIST
for y in ${x[@]}
    do
        cat $y
    done
```

Comment: What are the current setting of include-list and exclude-list. What does the script do ?

Comment: Where do you declare `INCLUDE_LIST`? What's `ILS`? `IFS`?

Comment: You never use the output of `gsettings`, you just overwrite the variable

Comment: What do you mean by that? @thatotherguy

Comment: Not sure how to explain it clearer than that. You assign the output of `gsettings`to a variable `y`. You then overwrite the variable `y` with a different value before ever accessing it. The output of `gsettings` is therefore just discarded. Your code effectively would just write the output of a *file* named `y` (the letter, not the contents of the variable) no matter what `gsettings` outputs